# Java: Can we use multi HashMap to group the resultset

Tags: java, sql-server

Prerequisites: Java 7 and SQL Server 2016.

I am getting a result set returned by stored procedure from SQL Server

ResultSet:

```
RId ConId  ActNbr StageId  Qty   HoursInStage HoursPassed HourlyQty FlowedQty
--- ------ ------ ------- ------ ------------ ----------- --------- ---------
50  6814     77     1     24000      24           0           NULL     NULL
50  6814     77     2     36000      19           5           NULL     NULL
50  6814     77     3     48000      15           9           NULL     NULL
50  6814     77     4     60000      11           13          NULL     NULL
50  6814     77     6     60000      24           0           NULL     NULL
50  6855     33     1     0          24           0           NULL     NULL
50  6855     33     2     15000      19           5           NULL     NULL
50  6855     33     3     15000      15           9           NULL     NULL
50  6855     33     4     15000      11           13          NULL     NULL
50  6855     33     6     20000      24           0           NULL     NULL
50  176892   10     1     0          24           0           NULL     NULL
50  176892   10     2     0          19           5           NULL     NULL
50  176892   10     3     0          15           9           NULL     NULL
50  176892   10     4     0          11           13          NULL     NULL
50  176892   10     6     0          24           0           NULL     NULL
50  176892   47     1     0          24           0           NULL     NULL
50  176892   47     2     0          19           5           NULL     NULL
50  176892   47     3     0          15           9           NULL     NULL
50  176892   47     4     0          11           13          NULL     NULL
50  176892   47     6     0          24           0           NULL     NULL
```

I have created a POJO class to hold the result set into.
I want to create a Hashmap object with Key as `RId`, `ConId`, `ActNbr` and Value as List that holds all the values for given key.

So, can I do that using HashMap? I thought I can use Map that holds other Map as Value. But not not sure how to make the common key value items as list.

Java Class: HoursQty

```
public class BurnProfileHourlyNomData {
    private Integer stageId;
    private Integer qty;
    private Integer hoursInStage;
    private Integer hoursPassed;
    private Integer hourlyQty;
    private Integer FlowedQty;
}
```

Logic:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, HoursQty>>> hourlyInfo = new HashMap<>();
for(DatabaseRecord row : rows) {
    Integer rId = (Integer)row.get("RId");
    Integer conId = (Integer)row.get("ConId");
    Integer actNbr = (Integer)row.get("ActNbr");
    Integer stageId = (Integer)row.get("StageId");
    Integer qty = (Integer)row.get("Qty");
    Integer hoursInStage = (Integer)row.get("HoursInStage");
    Integer hoursPassed = (Integer)row.get("HoursPassed");
    Integer hourlyQty = (Integer)row.get("HourlyQty");
    Integer flowedQty = (Integer)row.get("FlowedQty");

    HoursQty impl = new HoursQty();
    impl.setRId(rId);
    /* Performed all set methods to assign values */
    .....
    Map<Integer, HoursQty> actNbrMap = new HashMap<Integer, HoursQty>();
    actNbrMap.put(actNbr, impl);

    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, HoursQty>> conIdMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, HoursQty>>();
    conIdMap.put(conId, actNbrMap);

    hourlyInfo.put(rId, conIdMap);
}
```

tried to read this using entryMap key and value, but gets individual row value.
Not sure how to group all the list based on `rId`, `conId` and `actNbr` as key and retrieve all rows that has same key as the list.

Comment: Create an object having fields like RId, ConId, ActNbr, override equals and hashcode, use this object as key and other object as value in HashMap.

Comment: @Sambit please add that as an answer here. It should be the most suitable solution for this question.

Comment: I have added the answer, please check and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to design your class like this.

Class AccountKey which will be used as Key in HashMap. The code is given below.

```
public class AccountKey {
  private Integer rId;
  private Integer conId;
  private Integer actNbr;

  public Integer getrId() {
    return rId;
  }

  public void setrId(Integer rId) {
    this.rId = rId;
  }

  public Integer getConId() {
    return conId;
  }

  public void setConId(Integer conId) {
    this.conId = conId;
  }

  public Integer getActNbr() {
    return actNbr;
  }

  public void setActNbr(Integer actNbr) {
    this.actNbr = actNbr;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    AccountKey that = (AccountKey) o;

    if (rId != null ? !rId.equals(that.rId) : that.rId != null) return false;
    if (conId != null ? !conId.equals(that.conId) : that.conId != null) return false;
    return actNbr != null ? actNbr.equals(that.actNbr) : that.actNbr == null;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = rId != null ? rId.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (conId != null ? conId.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (actNbr != null ? actNbr.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Class BurnProfileHourlyNomData will be used as value in HashMap.

```
public class BurnProfileHourlyNomData {
  private Integer stageId;
  private Integer qty;
  private Integer hoursInStage;
  private Integer hoursPassed;
  private Integer hourlyQty;
  private Integer FlowedQty;

  public Integer getStageId() {
    return stageId;
  }

  public void setStageId(Integer stageId) {
    this.stageId = stageId;
  }

  public Integer getQty() {
    return qty;
  }

  public void setQty(Integer qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
  }

  public Integer getHoursInStage() {
    return hoursInStage;
  }

  public void setHoursInStage(Integer hoursInStage) {
    this.hoursInStage = hoursInStage;
  }

  public Integer getHoursPassed() {
    return hoursPassed;
  }

  public void setHoursPassed(Integer hoursPassed) {
    this.hoursPassed = hoursPassed;
  }

  public Integer getHourlyQty() {
    return hourlyQty;
  }

  public void setHourlyQty(Integer hourlyQty) {
    this.hourlyQty = hourlyQty;
  }

  public Integer getFlowedQty() {
    return FlowedQty;
  }

  public void setFlowedQty(Integer flowedQty) {
    FlowedQty = flowedQty;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    BurnProfileHourlyNomData that = (BurnProfileHourlyNomData) o;

    if (stageId != null ? !stageId.equals(that.stageId) : that.stageId != null) return false;
    if (qty != null ? !qty.equals(that.qty) : that.qty != null) return false;
    if (hoursInStage != null ? !hoursInStage.equals(that.hoursInStage) : that.hoursInStage != null)
      return false;
    if (hoursPassed != null ? !hoursPassed.equals(that.hoursPassed) : that.hoursPassed != null)
      return false;
    if (hourlyQty != null ? !hourlyQty.equals(that.hourlyQty) : that.hourlyQty != null)
      return false;
    return FlowedQty != null ? FlowedQty.equals(that.FlowedQty) : that.FlowedQty == null;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = stageId != null ? stageId.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (qty != null ? qty.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (hoursInStage != null ? hoursInStage.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (hoursPassed != null ? hoursPassed.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (hourlyQty != null ? hourlyQty.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (FlowedQty != null ? FlowedQty.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
  }
}
```

The structure of HashMap will be like this.

```
Map<AccountKey,BurnProfileHourlyNomData> actBurnDataMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Once you receive the data from stroed procedure, populate both the objects and use the Map given above.

Comment: Thank You @Sambit, that answers my question.